# Go, Golang : array type inside struct, missing type composite literal

Tags: go

I need to add slice type to this struct.

```
 type Example struct {
    text  []string
 }

 func main() {
    var arr = []Example {
        {{"a", "b", "c"}},
    }
    fmt.Println(arr)    
 }
```

Then I am getting

```
  prog.go:11: missing type in composite literal
  [process exited with non-zero status]
```

So specify the composite literal

```
    var arr = []Example {
         {Example{"a", "b", "c"}},
```

But still getting this error:

```
    cannot use "a" (type string) as type []string in field value
```

http://play.golang.org/p/XKv1uhgUId

How do I fix this? How do I construct the struct that contains array(slice) type?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here is your proper slice of `Example` struct:

```
[]Example{
  Example{
   []string{"a", "b", "c"},
  },
}
```

Let me explain it. You want to make a slice of `Example`. So here it is — `[]Example{}`. Then it must be populated with an `Example` — `Example{}`. `Example` in turn consists of `[]string` — `[]string{"a", "b", "c"}`. It just the matter of proper syntax.

Comment: How about this? It has more values and not working for another reason. Can't figure out

Comment: If you don't name your fields in the literal notation, you have to provide a value for all fields, otherwise name the field. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals . Working example based on yours: http://play.golang.org/p/13OSJHd5xe

Comment: Note that you don't need the second `Example` - go is smart enough to figure out that an `[]Example` is full of `Example` items without explicitly naming them. [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cx9dzBkG0P)