# "missing type in composite literal" in golang

Tags: json, go

Given these structs:

```
type InitRequest struct {
    ListenAddr      string
    ForceNewCluster bool
    Spec            Spec
}

type Spec struct {
    Annotations

    AcceptancePolicy AcceptancePolicy    `json:",omitempty"`
    //...
}

type AcceptancePolicy struct {
    Policies []Policy `json:",omitempty"`
}

type Policy struct {
    Role       NodeRole
    Autoaccept bool
    Secret     *string `json:",omitempty"`
}
```

This code doesn't compile, exiting on that line with *missing type in composite literal*. Followed [Go, Golang : array type inside struct, missing type composite literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482612/go-golang-array-type-inside-struct-missing-type-composite-literal) , but same error with:

```
swarm, err := cli.SwarmInit(context.Background(), swarm.InitRequest{
    ListenAddr:      "0.0.0.0:2377",
    ForceNewCluster: true,
    Spec: {
        AcceptancePolicy: {
            Policies: []Policy{
                Policy: {
                    Role:       "manager",
                    Autoaccept: true,
                },
            },
        }, // here
    },
})
```

Any hint will be very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I identified a few issues with your code:

1. Your Policies field in `AcceptancePolicy` is a slice not a map
2. You didn't specify the types of the `AcceptancePolicy` or the `Spec`.
3. You're naming a variable the same as the import package.
4. `Role` is a `NodeRole`, not a string

Here's your code with the above fixes implemented:

```
mySwarm, err := cli.SwarmInit(context.Background(), swarm.InitRequest{
    ListenAddr:      "0.0.0.0:2377",
    ForceNewCluster: true,
    Spec: swarm.Spec{
        AcceptancePolicy: swarm.AcceptancePolicy{
            Policies: []swarm.Policy{
                {
                    Role:       some.conversion.to.NodeRole("manager"),
                    Autoaccept: true,
                },
            },
        }, // here
    },
})
```